# \includegraphics{} compiling error - Dropbox

Tags: pdftex

In main.tex, I have `\subimport{relative_path_to_main}{sol.tex}`, and in directory/sol.tex, I have `\includegraphics[]{graph.pdf}`. However, I am getting this error message

> !pdfTeX error: /Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex (relative_path_to_main//graph.pdf): reading image file failed
> ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

Could someone help? thanks!

EDIT:

main.tex

a different folder

|-- sol.tex

|-- graph.pdf

If I comment out the included pdfs in sol.tex, my pdf is compiled successfully. If the pdfs are included, my pdf fails to be compiled.

Comment: No that's unlikely to be the issue. Describe what the location of the (main TeX file, included TeX file, image file).

Comment: Have updated it

Comment: `/` is a forward slash, not a backslash.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the reason. It turns out the files are online only in Dropbox, so the LaTex compiler has a problem reading them.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  This information would really be better edited into your question.

Comment: @barbarabeeton But it solves the question already. (we could probably close the question as "non-reproducible"/"too localized" but I don't see much point either way.)

Comment: @user202729 -- Just trying to keep the site tidy.  User answers that are so short like this one are rarely upvoted or accepted, so "Community" keeps adding them to the active list, which is annoying.